# filter many times a tibble

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a problem under R with dplyr
I have a tibble with 3 colomns (id, number of people, number of graduated)
I would like to do this

```
tibble = filter (number of people == 2000 & number of graduated < 2) %>%
         filter (number of people == 3000 & number of graduated < 3) %>%
         filter (number of people == 4000 & number of graduated < 4) ...
```

and to this till I go to the max len of my colomn

Then i'll do a bindrows in order to create a tibble with these rows

But how can I proceed ?

Comment: There are several problems here: 1. The first argument of `filter()` is the data frame, which is missing here. 2. Piping multiple filters one after the other makes no sense. It would make more sense perhaps to use different filters and assign them to different data frames, but it's not clear from your post what you're trying to do. 3. It's a bad idea to name an object with the name of an often used function name like `tibble()`. Give it a name that won't be confusing like `mydf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining filters like this means you're taking a subset of a subset of a subset, etc. But this will be empty right away, since a row can't have number_of_people == 2000 *and* == 3000, right? Maybe you mean "or" instead of "and"? It tough to infer what you're trying to do without seeing your data, since your question doesn't really make sense.

Here's my best guess:

```
# create some dummy data
data <- data.frame(
                number_of_people = 1000 * sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE),
                number_graduated = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
                )

# keep rows where graduates < people/1000
data <- data[data$number_graduated < data$number_of_people/1000, ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) it works but I need to do it with dplyr :/

Comment: Why? Doing this with dplyr is a bit like using a sledgehammer to push in a thumbtack.

Comment: Finally didn't have to use dplyr ^^